# Are Quick Connect Shark Bite Connectors Safe to use with a Boiler?

Tags: pipe, boiler

I have a section of piping I want to clean up, and while out to buy some supplies to practice my pipe sweating I found out about Quick Connect Shark Bite connectors. I was told they work for both residential water and boiler applications but I wanted to know of examples or things to look out for.

My boiler operates between 120 °F and 160 °F @ 12 psi to 25 psi with the high temp cutoff at 190 °F.

In the winters it's become necessary to run the heat 24/7 for about a week at a time, so softening of the plastic seal because of heat is something I am concerned with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SharkBite fittings are certified to 200 PSI and 200°F (93°C).

Lots more info available on the official shark bite website.

[Here is a link](https://www.sharkbite.com/resources/faqs/universal-brass-push-fittings-faqs)   to FAQ on the site where I found this answer.

Comment: My local store has Watts QuickConnect "Shark Bite" connectors, but I can't get their spec page to [load](https://www.watts.com/products/plumbing-flow-control-solutions/connections/quick-connect/quick-connect-couplings/lf4715) do you have any opinion? The link you posted is a good resource overall.

Comment: Are they the white plastic kind?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Watts-P-600-Connect-Coupling-2-Inch/dp/B000BQYATA.  The specs on amazon for their plastic 1/2” coupling shows 250 psi at 75 degreeF OR 100psi at 180 degreeF

Comment: Brass, so if the plastic meet the spec, I'm comfortable with the brass ones in an easily accessible space near the boiler. At this point if they last more than a year they would be twice as reliable as the system they are helping to replace.